# Modal not launching jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm following a bootsnipp example on setting up a modal sign up form, when I pasted the code to jsfiddle and click the button it doesn't launch. The bootsnipp is http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/sign-in-sign-up-dual-modal and the jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/SamuelMuiruri/DTcHh/9786/ The signup/register button code

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#signup" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-modal-sm">Sign In/Register</button>
```

the modal doesn't launch.

Comment: When I use Jquery 1.11, it works as expected, can you check your jquery version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bootstrap depends on jQuery. You didn't refer to jQuery in your Fiddle.:)

Not sure if you know about it but here is how to do it :

[image]

Comment: It answers the question, I tried updating to jquery 1.11, and it works as expected.